# Empty result with findAll in FlexForm UserFunc in TYPO3 7.6.15

Tags: repository, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

I get an empty result with findAll in FlexForm UserFunc in TYPO3 7.6.15.
The storagePid is set and in Frontend I get all results with findAll.

Here is my UserFunc-Method:

```
public function getBuldingOptions(&$config)
{
    /** @var ObjectManager $om */
    $om = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ObjectManager::class);

    /** @var BuildingRepository $repo */
    $repo = $om->get(BuildingRepository::class);
    $building = $repo->findAll();

    DebuggerUtility::var_dump($building, '$building'); // Output: TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\QueryResultprototypeobject (empty)

    // add empty value option
    $config['items'][] = [LocalizationUtility::translate('BuildingUserFunc.building.emtpyValue', $this->extName), 0];

    /** @var Building $entity */
    foreach ($building as $entity) {
        $config['items'][] = [$entity->getName(), $entity->getUid()];
    }

    return $config;
}
```

What can by still wrong? Anybody an idea?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem and a suitable solution.

The problem is, that the configured storagePid does not work in plugin configuration scope. You have to solve the storagePid manually.

I have wrote a service for that and added to EXT:xm_tools:

https://github.com/xima-media/xm_tools/blob/rc-1.0.0/Classes/Extensionmanager/ExtensionUtility.php

And my repository have a initializeObject method:

```
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Typo3QuerySettings;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Repository;
use Xima\XmTools\Extensionmanager\ExtensionUtility;

class BaseRepository extends Repository
{

    private $extName = 'my_extension_key';

    public function initializeObject()
    {
        $pluginSetup = ExtensionUtility::getTypoScriptPluginSetup($this->extName);

        /** @var Typo3QuerySettings $querySettings */
        $querySettings = $this->objectManager->get(Typo3QuerySettings::class);
        $querySettings->setStoragePageIds(array_merge($querySettings->getStoragePageIds(), explode(',', $pluginSetup['persistence']['storagePid'])));
        $this->setDefaultQuerySettings($querySettings);
    }

}
```